# Assigning click event handler inside keyup event causes the click event to be fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am attempting to add an event handler to an anchor only when certain form fields are populated, like so:

```
$('#newName, #newFrom').keyup(function (e) {
    if ($('#newName').val() || $('#newFrom').val()) {
        $('#add-person').click(function (e) {
            //Handle event, includes adding a row to a table.
            $('this').off();
        });
    }
});
```

It seems like the first event is getting propagated to the second one since I end up with the same number of rows in my table as keys I have typed.

I've tried adding

```
    e.stopPropagation();
```

But with no success.

Comment: Could your issue be that `if ($('#newName').val() || $('#newFrom').val()) {` is not checking anything?

Comment: That is checking for a non empty string in my form fields with those IDs?  That bit seems to work tbh.

Comment: Oh ok. I had never seen that used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('this').off();` should be `$(this).off();`
also probably you'd better go using the `input` event instead of `keyup`. `input` event will trigger even if one pastes content into your fields.

nevertheless I'd go the other way around:

```
// (cache your selectors)
var $newName = $("#newName"),
    $newFrom = $("#newFrom");

// create a boolean flag
var haveNewValue = false;

// modify that flag on fields `input`
$newName.add( $newFrom ).on("input", function() {
  haveNewValue = ($.trim($newName.val()) + $.trim($newFrom.val())).length > 0;
});

// than inside the click test your flag
$('#add-person').click(function (e) {
  if(!haveNewValue) return; // exit function if no entered value.

  // do stuff like adding row to table
});
```

**What was wrong:**

on every `keyup` you was assigning a new (therefore multiple) `click` event/s to the button, but the (*corrected to:*) `$(this).off()` was triggered only after an actual button click.

Also a better way to use `.on()` and `off.()` (notice the difference in using the `.click()` method and the `.on()` method) is:

```
function doCoffee() {
  alert("Bzzzzzzzz...BLURGGUZRGUZRGUZRG");
}

$("#doCoffeeButton").on("click", doCoffee); // Register "event" using .on()

$("#bossAlertButton").click(function() {
   $("#doCoffeeButton").off("click");       // Turn off "event" using .off()
});
```

Comment: This does work!  I'd love to know why what I was doing didn't work though, even after changing to this (without quotes - doh!) and input.

Comment: @Sam expanded my answer ;)

Comment: Not sure what happened.  Thanks for the explanation!!